# Enforce updating locale format after locale switch

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, locale

I use [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/) in my React project. I've implemented the locale configuration via React Context API but it turns out that changing the global locale of `momentjs` doesn't affect existing objects. It's a feature since version 2.8.0, see [Changing locale globally](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/).

```
moment.locale();       // 'en'
const m = moment();
m.format("L");         // 11/01/2018
moment.locale("de"));  // 'de'
m.format("L");         // 11/01/2018
```

The `LocaleProvider` component switches the locales.

```
// LocaleProvider class component
onChangeLocale = locale => moment.locale(locale);
```

A child component renders a locale specific `momentjs` instance.

```
// child element class component
render() {
  const { currentDate } = this.state;
  return <div>{currentDate.format("L")}<div>;
}
```

How could I enforce existing `momentjs` object to use the changed locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the global `locale` explicitly with `moment.locale()` when rendering the component.

```
// child element class component
import moment from "moment";

render() {
  const { currentDate } = this.state;
  return <div>{currentDate.locale(moment.locale()).format("L")}<div>;
}
```